# Noob camera view problem

Tags: camera

When in camera view you have a rectangle that you view from and everything else around is kinda greyed out , well in my camera view the right side edge is cut off , i cant see it even if i move the camera or change focal length,I don’t know what I did or how to change it back...[image]

Comment: You most probably have "Lock Camera to View" enabled, under "Properties" (key N) > "View" > "Lock Camera to View" (uncheck it). Yo ucan enter/leave the camera perspective with "Numpad 0", no matter if locked to view or not.

Comment: I voted this question down because I consider it to be not showing any research effort. Shift+middle mouse button drag will resolve the issue, if not, hit n, ant find and untick 'Lock Camera to View' in the panel on the right of the 3d view. The basics will be extremely hard to learn by asking online about them. I would reccommend watching some basic tutorials(on Youtube for example) and getting to know the basic functions on your own.

Comment: If you're on a Mac and using a trackpad, use Shift+two-finger scroll instead. No need for a three-button mouse.

Comment: Also, screenshots are generally better than pictures of your screen, unless you can't take them for some reason (e.g. your computer won't boot). Looks like you're on a Mac, try ⇧⌘4, then Space. (:

Comment: Lock camera to view wasn’t checked... I tried shift+middle mouse button, i was playing with all camera settings to see what they did and after a while I noticed that I had a cut screen but thanks for the help, I just closed blender and reopened it and it was back to normal... not sure what i did it working fine now... thanks again for the quick replies...

Comment: Try sliding over using the Shift key and the touch pad ( assuming that you don’t have a mouse)